# Add undeleteable content to contentEditable div

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to add a minimum Content to a contentEdiatable div ?

I needed an input element that could take children, so I created my own with a div. The problem is that you are not allowed to edit a contentEditable element if it has 0 characters in it. So I placed a 0-width character inside the div to mitigate the issue & I am currently using javascript to make sure that the content always at least contains that 0-width character.

Is there a way to have undeletable content in an contenteditable element without js?

Comment: _"you are not allowed to edit a contentEditable element"_ - sounds like an XY-Problem. _"So I placed a 0-width character inside the div"_ - sounds like a whacky hack. Can't you just omit the `contenteditable` attribute for empty input fields when rendering the page/template?

Comment: @domsson _I needed an input element that can take children_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is impossible, javascript is the way to go here.